# Need help configuring IIS 5.1 on XP

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-xp

Fist of all I want to say IIS to me is like a vending machine to a monkey.

So I have Windows XP SP2 with IIS 5.1 on it and an ASP.NET Web Forms project. I just want my website to be accessed by someone else from the internet or from my local network. How do I configure IIS so that is possible?

I tried a lot of user guides, but I don't know what I did wrong cause all I got was Page not foud and Service Unavailable.

Thanks in advance for all your guidance and answers.

Comment: Are you trying to host a website on your PC at home/office and make it available on the internet?

Comment: Do you have use the iis snap in confiuration tool ? \inetsrv\iis.msc

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to host a web site and make it available on the internet. No, I didn't use IIS snap-in configuration tool, but thanks for telling me, I'll search the to see what it's about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I managed to make it work. I just had to find a few, good user guides and to repair a problem with ASP.NET instances on the IIS server.